# Is mongodb performance slower when disk storage almost full

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, server

I'm still new for using mongodb database.

I thing mongodb is quite good, but now i have some issue.

I have java apps with mongodb and now it's running on production server for 3-4 months. The storage that allocated for mongodb is 1,5T. The server is redhat with mongodb v3.2.

In 1 to 2 month is good because the storage still bellow 60% of the allocated storage. But some reason after the disk above 80% the process is slower and become slower.

The mongodb server is single node, not using replica set or sharding.

And my questions:

1. Is this normal?
2. If yes, is there any idea to solve this problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, with the above details it is difficult to debug the issue. Have you seen frequent memory swapping on your database server? What is the RAM of your database? Dataset size? Is there a lot of disk I/O? How about the indexes?

Comment: Do you have measurements of your IO performance times from when you first started?  Because yes, this is normal - as the file system fills up, it's going to take longer find unallocated space to put new data, and it's also going to take longer to search through the used space to find requested data.  The easiest solution?  Put the data on a faster disk system.  There's a reason faster disk systems are sold. Writing *fast* IO code is hard, and the solution tends to be very design-specific, and programming time is expensive compared to just buying some fast hardware.

Comment: Do you try to create an index ? Without indexes, MongoDB scan every document in a collection to select those documents that match the query statement. Indexes can limit the number of documents parsed. Also you need more RAM for indexes.